# How to programmatically update item on master database from Content Delivery MVC Sitecore 8

Tags: mvc, sitecore-services-client

I have the following scenario on Sitecore 8.2 (MVC Project)
I have a scaled Sitecore (CM/CD), and after the user hits a page on CD Server, it needs to update a Sitecore Item, that contains a field called `Counter` and this must be republished as well, triggered by the code, at the same time.

I know it's possible to perform this operation using Javascript (`Sitecore Services Client`), but I'm afraid of using that due to Security. Which would be the best approach to perform that?

Note that, I cannot use `.GetDatabase("Master")`

Thank You

Comment: Are you saying that every time that someone visits your site, you want to update an item on master, and then publish?

Comment: Is the `Counter` field going to be incremented with each page view?

Comment: Can you provide some context as to why you need to do this Jose? This sounds like all kinds of bad practice. Usually if you are tracking page views, why wouldn't you just track this with Sitecore analytics? Some context will better describe your problem and then somebody can provide a better suggestion for a solution to your underlying issue.

Comment: I don't know the details of the use case, but in general I agree with the above, this is not the correct way to solve this problem, for performance and security reasons.

Comment: Hi, this will not be related to the Page Views, this will be triggered only if the user Make a Donation to the website, which does not happen often

Comment: Jose are you using xDB or CMS Only?

Comment: I´m using both, any suggestion on xDB would be good as well, there is on constraint, the user must be able to edit or override the value as well

Comment: Since it isn't content, best to stay out of the content items that go through workflow, versioning, and publishing. Thanks for the clarifications, some good answers coming from this!

Comment: Jose, when you say that "this will be triggered only if the user Make a Donation" then that sounds like it could be a Goal, Conversion, and/or an Event in xDB, depending on how you want to configure your site's analytics. Assuming that the form isn't wired up to analytics already and isn't a WFFM form, then the simplest solution is likely to be a custom page event, as described in the below solution from @AdamSeabridge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have xDB enabled you could perhaps use MongoDB to store your data instead.

There look to be a few approaches for doing this:

**1) custom page events:**

This looks like your best bet, Here are Sitecore's official docs for this:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/marketing_operations/events/register_a_page_event_programmatically

You can then do something like:

```
MyPageDataService service = new MyPageDataService();
service.MyPageDataService("Goal", "Donated", "£100", string.Empty);
```

Some examples from around the web of doing this:
https://pramisoni.wordpress.com/2017/02/27/sitecore-analytics-tracking-on-click-of-events/
https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SitecoreV3/Handling+Custom+Events;jsessionid=A59AE33C36B1AB36ED6906785D67547C

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/10/07/sitecore-register-page-events/

**2) a page aggregation table:**

This looks more complex to do:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_creating_a_rate_page_custom_aggregation

Comment: I like this better! +1

Comment: Hi, the ideia using mongo is good, but the user must be able to override or reset this number as well , i will take a look on those examples

Answer (score 0):

**If you have xdb enabled see Adam Seabridge's post**

I think I would keep this data in a separate sql table. Sql has an atomic increment operation which is something you'll want for this. You also probably don't want that field to be editable in any way by a content editor. Then you would be dealing with a connection string to decide where to pull/write the data based on the environment. I do generally try to avoid a custom db outside of Sitecore but I'm not seeing a great alternative.

As far as I know there is no atomic increment option for a Sitecore field. You might be able to get away with a custom api using a field if you lock before reading the number of times a donation happened and then update it but it just seems like a lot of hoops to go through to edit the master db to then publish that up to the web db. Putting this in a field would also give me cause to pause when it comes to anything that would by default update the master db (submitting a test donation while previewing the page).

Comment: Hello, one of the requirements is that the field should be editable , that is why i first thought, on edting the master and publishing the web

Comment: @Jose that makes sense. This is an interesting use case. If it does need to be content manageable and update based on functionality I don't have a great answer. If it just needs to be able to be reset maybe you can go with Adam's answer but allow the content editor to set a date that can be used to count donation events from that date onward?